# is it possible to run AutoML model on device using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I have trained a model in Firebase AutoML and downloaded it

```
dict.txt
manifest.json
model.tflite
```

But i don't know how to use it. I tried this [Running AutoML Models with Flutter](https://blog.usejournal.com/running-automl-models-with-flutter-automl-vision-edge-38038139cb14) but didn't work because this package miss `FirebaseVisionImage`  . In [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision) changelog i found this

> 0.6.0 # Breaking Change Removed on-device model dependencies from plugin. Android now requires adding the on-device label detector
>   dependency manually. iOS now requires adding the on-device
>   barcode/face/label/text detector dependencies manually.

How to add on-device label detector dependency manually ?

Comment: did you find anything since then?